# CTE can be use multiply times in a procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have a question about CTE:

In my procedure I use 2 times a CTE but only the first is considerate.

When I execute the second CTE in a single query it works !

So my question is : It is possible to execute many cte in a procedure ?

Thanks for help !

(I can edit my post if you want to see my ps)

```
with CatAvg as
(
    select COLUMNS
        , CatAverage = AVG(AV)
    from geographie.T_DIM_CHAL
    group by COLUMNS
)
update c
set COLUMN_TWO = ca.CatAverage
from geographie.T_DIM_CHAL c
join CatAvg ca on ca.COLUMNS = c.COLUMNS;

with CatAvgDep as
(
    select COLUMN_THREE
        , CatAverageDep = AVG(AV)
    from geographie.T_DIM_CHAL
    group by COLUMN_THREE
)
update d
set DEP = ca.CatAverageDep
from geographie.T_DIM_CHAL d
join CatAvgDep ca on ca.COLUMN_THREE = d.COLUMN_THREE;
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use multiple CTE in a procedure, edit your question to show what isn't working for you, add any errors if you get them, add output you get and output you expect.

Comment: A CTE is an _expression_, not an object. It can be referenced multiple times _in a single query_. If you need to use it in _multiple_ queries, materialize it to a #temp table instead.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "only the first is considerate". A [mcve] might help us understand your question better. (Please make sure it's **minimal**, so don't post your complete procedure here. And also make sure it's **complete**, so make sure the reduced version compiles.)

Comment: @Aarlaneth i edited my post, I got no error when i exec my ps
I just want that my columns three is update with new values

Comment: You're updating all of the rows with the average? How often are you doing this? It seems silly to me to constantly update the data since it will change any time you update a single row, with something you can always calculate at runtime. This smells like premature optimization.

Comment: I juste update 3 columns not all of them. And that will be updating 1 time per year

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with these. Did you try running them together but outside of procedure (like you posted them now)? Also, it would help immensly if you would add table structure, sample data and this queries as a stored procedure.

Comment: Also, post your whole procedure becouse it is possible problem is outside of this queries ( considering they both work seperatly)

Comment: (I think maybe you're mixing up rows and columns.)

Comment: @Aarlaneth yeah I try to running them together in a simple query and that's works. 
I will edit my post to put the struct of my table

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker not possible they works when i executed them in a simple query

Comment: @Yes Interesting, then problem must be in something else inside your procedure, you can try few things to debug. If your stored procedure contains other code too, create new stored procedure, add these 2 queries and run just that. If that works, add part by part your code from stored procedure and see at what point it breaks.

Comment: That way you can come to minimal code needed to reproduce this problem. Then if you also add your table structure and sample data we can help you solve it.

Comment: @Aarlaneth yeah i try to detect where my CTE is not passing. 
I will update my post if don't find it !
thanks for your help :)

Comment: I have one more questions sorry,  it is a problem if the CTE is at the end of a procedure ? 
PS : When I separated my 2 CTE into a another ps that works !

Comment: Place in procedure doesn't influence CTE in itself. Only thing that does is what code is in front of it. Considering they work on their own, I would start by looking at code that is in front of second CTE, and from there work upwards. Something must be stoping it from working. What you can also do is instead of doing UPDATE statement with CTE, do SELECT, run your SP manually through database and look at output. Does it select values that you would like to be updated?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help  @Aarlaneth :) , I just create an another ps and exec him in my first ps ! I will check why my ps block the second cte later when I have more time.
I'm a student, i don't have already all the goods basics in my head !

Comment: @Aarlaneth I find why that's doesn't work, If you don't use a CTE at the begining of your ps or query : put a ; before the with that will work ! 
I hope that will be helpfull for sombody else with the same problems